# Java ASSERTION error in grails

Tags: java, grails

I am getting the following error:

```
  *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
 *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
 | Error 2014-08-28 09:25:11,399 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -  StackOverflowError occurred when processing request: [GET] /api/getProduct - parameters:
 id: 14
 Stacktrace follows:
 Message: Executing action [getProduct] of controller [project.ApiController]  caused exception:  Runtime error executing action
     Line | Method
 ->>  198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
 |     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
 |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
 |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
 ^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

my domains are as follows:

```
 class Product {
 String name
 String comments
 static hasMany = [components:Components]

 public asJSON(){
      println "product: "+this.id
    def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    def root = builder {
        id this.id
        name this.name
        comments this.comments
        components this.components.collect {it.asJSON()}

        }

    return builder.toString().replaceAll(/\\"/, '"').replaceAll(/\"\{/,'{').replaceAll(/\}\"/,'}')
 }
 }
```

Component:

```
class Components {
Product part_of
static hasMany = [alternatives:Alternatives]

public String asJSON(){
    def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    def root = builder {
        id this.id
        product (this.part_of)?this.part_of.asJSON():null
      //  alternatives (this.alternatives)?this.alternatives.collect {it.product.productAsJSON()} :null
    }

    return builder.toString()
}

}
```

When I do the following I get the exception

```
 Product.get(1).asJSON()
```

I have checked that it is not recursively calling itself.
Product 1 have one Component which has a Product instance called part_of which is product with the ID 5

Comment: can it be that `components this.components.collect {it.asJSON()}` and `product (this.part_of)?this.part_of.asJSON():null` is the recursion?

Comment: no I have checked this. It seems to move through until it finds a product which has no components and then throws this error.